# Update Values of a field in structure | Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a structure (sa1) with fields : FirstImpression, FashionSense, Compatibility (7*1) size

I want to find the indexes of maximum value of FirstImpression & Fashion Sense and increment the value of Compatibility by 1 on the same index.

I have found the indexes of maximum value, However, I am finding it difficult to increment the compatibility value on those indexes.

Can you suggest a way ? Here is the code :

```
firstImpression = zeros(1,size(sa1(),2));
fashionSense = zeros(1,size(sa1(),2));

for i=1:(size(sa1(),2))
firstImpression(i) = sa1(i).FirstImpression;
fashionSense(i) = sa1(i).FashionSense;
end

maxFirstImpressionScore = max(firstImpression);
maxFashionSenseScore = max(fashionSense);
maxFirstImpressionScoreIndexes = find(firstImpression == maxFirstImpressionScore);
maxFashionSenseScoreIndexes = find(fashionSense == maxFashionSenseScore);

for k = 1:size(maxFashionSenseScoreIndexes,2)
    sa1(maxFashionSenseScoreIndexes(k)).Compatibility = sa1(maxFashionSenseScoreIndexes(k)).Compatibility +1;
end
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dot notation on an array of `struct` entries yields a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which can be used to form arrays. You can then operate on these arrays rather than looping through the `struct` every time. For your problem, you could use something like:

```
% Create an array of firstImpression values and find the maximum value
mx1 = max([sa1.firstImpression]);

% Create an array of fashionSense values and find the maximum value
mx2 = max([sa1.fashionSense]);

% Create a mask the size of sa1 that is TRUE where it was equal to the max of each
mask1 = [sa1.firstImpression] == mx1;
mask2 = [sa1.fashionSense] == mx2;

% Increase the Compatibility of struct that was either a max of firstImpression or 
% fashionSense
compat = num2cell([sa1(mask1 | mask2).Compatibility] + 1);

% Replace those values with the new Compatibilty values
[sa1(mask1 | mask2).Compatibility] = compat{:};
```

Comment: Thanks. You have taught me a lot in this small piece of code. Thanks !!

Comment: Suppose, the code you have written is in IF loop and after the successful if loop, I want to reset the compatibility value to its original value ? Then how would be do that ?

Comment: @amansaraf You could repeat the last two lines (and modify them a little) to re-assign different values.